# how to watch wifi networks in the android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I would like to know if it is possible to connect the android emulator to the wifi card to detect the available networks and connect to them.

I am trying to use a library for drive drones and first, I need to be connected to the drone's wifi network but in the android emulator the networks do not appear, there is only one by default that is wifiAndroid.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. I suspect that you will need to test using Android hardware.